# I am trying to use font awesome. Can i dynamically load to the cards but I am stuck as to how i put this in my displayImage function?

Tags: javascript

```
//array for to hold font awesome icons for cards.
var tileImages=["fa fa-plane","fa fa-bus","fa fa-child","fa fa-tree","fa 
fa-thumbs-up","fa fa-umbrella"];
//console.log(tileImages);
var gameboard = document.getElementById("gameboard");

var solutionArray=tileImages.concat(tileImages);
//console.log(solutionArray);
shuffleArray(solutionArray);
//console.log(solutionArray);


startGame();

function startGame(){
// clear gameboard
document .getElementById("gameboard").innerHTML="";
//Gameboard Create
for (var i= 0; i <= (solutionArray.length=11); i ++){
displayImage(i);
}
}
```

/*
    I am trying bootstrap and would like to load icons to my tiles for a 
    memory game. Is this possible? These are the columns I have added using bootstrap CDN. I also added font awesome CDN to the HTML. Thank you in advance.
*/

```
function displayImage(i){
//console.log(i);
gameboard.innerHTML += '<div class="col-s-4 col-xs-3 gametile">'+i+' 
</div>';
}
```

Comment: What issue did you face?

Comment: I can not get the font awesome icons to show on the tiles in the browser.  When I console.log the array is there. Not sure how to add the font awesome icon array to displayImage function. Thank you.

Comment: can you create a snippet to work on

Comment: Check and let me know is this is what you looking http://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/s436kh10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to dynamically generate font awesome icon.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("app");
var tileImages=["fa fa-plane","fa fa-bus","fa fa-child","fa fa-tree","fa fa-thumbs-up","fa fa-umbrella"];
tileImages.forEach(item1=>{
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  var iTag = document.createElement('i');
  iTag.setAttribute('aria-hidden',"true");
  iTag.setAttribute('class',item1)
  node.appendChild(iTag);
  ele.appendChild(node);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app">

</div>
```

Comment: Here is the forked version of you pen https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/gjvGQV. If  it helped accept the answer..thanks